# Is there any way to pop an alert in a page only after a .php file has finished executing in php server?

Tags: javascript, php, html, xmlhttprequest

is there any way to pop an alert only after a .php file running from php server is done executing? this may be the only way to fix my problem if there is...

my .php is:

```
<?php
$output = exec("arduino_debug.exe --upload RIKDuino\RIKDuino.ino
IF !ERRORLEVEL! == 0 (
echo upload success!!
pause)

IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 (
echo upload failed
pause) 2>&1" );

echo $output;
?>
```

my function that executes the .php file in my html page

```
function UploadToRIK()
{
ForIde();
var xmlhttp;
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
  if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status== 200)
  {}

}
xmlhttp.open("POST","Arduino/upload.php",true);
if(window.confirm ('Code will be Uplaoded to RIK Robot! Please Press OK to Continue...'))
{

xmlhttp.send("upld");
}


}
```

Comment: Try jquery ajax function look here https://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Just add the logic you want inside the callback function which is attached to the `onreadystatechange` event:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
  if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status== 200)
  {
      //put some logic, for example:
      alert('All good! ' + xmlhttp.responseText);
  }

}
```

This way you will see the alert popping out when a response is received (and the http status is 200), after your PHP script finishes.

You can also check for other states (or http statuses different from 200), in the case of failure, for example and treat them properly.

For further info about it, try 
[readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState)
and
[XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Thank you so much... ive spent 2 nights figuring this, XD

Comment: you're welcome. Good luck and have a look at the links anyway, you might have some good insights.